# jQuery remote validate against email verification service

Tags: jquery, validation, email

I need to validate email against email verification service.

Problem is that i have no control of the service php. 
The service returns "valid" and "invalid" response.

As far as I understand jQuery validate asks for true or false.

The remote url is http://i2srv.com/validate/

Example :http://i2srv.com/validate/?email=skyhawk133@gmail.com
It has to be sent in this format.

This is what i have tried.

```
remote: {      
    url: "http://i2srv.com/validate/",
    type: "post",
    complete: function(data) {
        if( data.responseText == "valid" ) {
            alert("Email is OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation options for the `remote` method deep-extend the defaults `(dataType:"json", data:{nameOfTheElement:valueOfTheElement})`. Any options you provide will override the defaults.

**AND MOST IMPORTANT**

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a GET parameter.

so you do not have to use the `post` method, just change `dataType` to `html`

```
remote: {
      url: "https://i2srv.com/validate/",
      dataType: 'html',
      complete: function(data) {
        if (data.responseText == "valid") {
          alert("Email is OK");
        }
      }
    }
```

See the demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signupform").validate({
    rules: {
      firstname: "required",
      lastname: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
          url: "https://i2srv.com/validate/",
          dataType: 'html',
          complete: function(data) {
            if (data.responseText == "valid") {
              alert("Email is OK");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      firstname: "please enter firstname",
      lastname: "please enter firstname",
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div id="signupwrap">
  <form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">
          <label id="lfirstname" for="firstname">First Name</label>
        </td>
        <td class="field">
          <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td class="status"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">
          <label id="llastname" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        </td>
        <td class="field">
          <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" value="" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td class="status"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="label">
          <label id="lemail" for="email">Email Address</label>
        </td>
        <td class="field">
          <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" maxlength="150">
        </td>
        <td class="status"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="label">
          <label id="lsignupsubmit" for="signupsubmit">Signup</label>
        </td>
        <td class="field" colspan="2">
          <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Great! I am getting a response from the remote now.
Only thing is that it is always not validated(it is always error). With error messages "valid" or "invalid", depending if email is valid or not.

Comment: if you use the demo above and provide the same email that you have provided it will give you valid, and the `alert` say `Email is OK`, so that means email is validated if you are not getting the response in your script then compare your code with above carefully. user `skyhawk133@gmail.com` in aboveform inside email and press signup.

Comment: and please select the answer as correct if it works for you @user2767441

Comment: First, thanks for your help so much!
Alert is working fine, and I get valid/invalid returned.
But the form will still not submit as it sees the email field as error.
Even when I "Run Code Snippet" of the code abode, it does the same.